# How do I index a sub array to keep the order of the original array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My model consists of:

```
struct SomeModel {
    let selectedIndex: Int
    //...
}
```

And my subarray consists of a filtered array of the above type which feeds in to my collection view:

```
var modelFeedArray = [SomeModel]()
var filteredModelFeedArray = [SomeModel]()

//..

for model in modelFeedArray {
    if <#condition#> {
        filteredModelFeedArray.append(model)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: <#T##Int#>, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do i index my subarray to keep the order of the original array, or in other words, what should the `row` argument in `init(row:section:)` be?

--

One idea is re-mapping the indices of the subarray elements to range `0..<filteredModelFeedArray.count`, but that is unsatisfactory if i were to change the index of my model through `moveItem(at:to:)`

Comment: What is the index of the first row?

Comment: For the filtered array, it will depend what selectedIndex property the model that was filtered contains.

Comment: Since you ***append*** the filtered items to `filteredModelFeedArray` the first index is `filteredModelFeedArray.count - 1`. So append the items, then create a range from that index to `filteredModelFeedArray.endIndex`, map it to `[IndexPath]` and call `insertItems`. The order is kept anyway. Or use `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`.